# Worksheet change event occuring multiple times only when inserting row(s)

Tags: excel, vba, undo

I'm upgrading a moderately complicated Excel spreadsheet which validates user input, otherwise the spreadsheet can be very easily broken. Part of this validation involves ensuring certain cells with data needed for the spreadsheet to operate are not deleted. To achieve this I have the submodule

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim errMsg As String

    On Error GoTo turnAutomationOn:
    Call turnOffExcelFeatures
    Worksheets(WORKSHEET_NAME).UsedRange 'gets rid of ghost cells

    ' check critical data and forumlae have not been disturbed or deleted

    If errMsg <> "" Then
        Call outputErrorMessage(errMsg)   ' definitely works
        Call undoLastAction()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' process change made

turnAutomationOn:
    Call turnOnExcelFeatures
End Sub
```

where the functions `turnOffExcelFeatures()`, `turnOnExcelFeatures()`, and `undoLastAction()` are defined as

```vb
' Increase performance by turning of certian Excel features
' WARNING: Make sure to call turnOnExcelFeatures() before calling function/sub ends!
Public Function turnOffExcelFeatures()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
End Function

' Turns Excel features back on that are turned off by turnOffExcelFeatures()
Public Function turnOnExcelFeatures()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Function

Public Function undoLastAction()
    On Error Resume Next ' in case Application.Undo fails due to empty undo stack

    Dim enableEventsStatus As Boolean

    With Application
        enableEventsStatus = .EnableEvents
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Undo
        .EnableEvents = enableEventsStatus
    End With
End Function
```

Generally speaking, this code works just fine. However, when inserting row(s) the `undoLastAction()` function is being called a second time. This makes the script stop at the `.Undo` line, where Excel outputs a Run-time error '1004'. I'm guessing this is because the first run of the `Worksheet_change()` sub clears the undo stack. Strangely, this only occurs when inserting a new row(s); changing a cell value, inserting columns, deleting columns, and deleting rows don't have the same issue.

After experimenting with breakpoints, I can confirm that the `Worksheet_change()` sub is being run multiple times **only** when inserting new row(s).

Considering my usage of setting of the `EnableEvents` variable, I don't understand why inserting new rows would cause the worksheet change event to occur. I've tried searching for `EnableEvents` via Ctrl + F, but I can only find it in the `turnOffExcelFeatures()` and `turnOnExcelFeatures()` functions. Furthermore, the `On Error Resume Next` in the `undoLastAction()` doesn't appear to do anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you pause the procedure when inside the `undoLastAction` and check the `EnableEvents` status in the debug window, what does it return? True or False?

Comment: `Call turnOffExcelFeatures` should be before `If errMsg <> "" Then`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and updated my question but still got the exact same problem. At least deleting rows still works.

Comment: @Damian Exactly what I expect. ```EnableEvents``` is ```True``` when the sub starts, becomes ```False``` during execution of ```turnOffExcelFeatures()```, only becoming ```True``` when ```turnOnExcelFeatures()``` is called.